# Fedora24, trying to install java (JDK)

Tags: fedora, java, jdk

I've installed `openjdk`

```
Installed Packages 
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64          1:1.8.0.101-1.b14.fc24   @updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.101-1.b14.fc24   @updates     
javapackages-tools.noarch          4.6.0-14.fc24            @koji-override-0
```

but still. can't find `javac`  (there is only `java` program). Where is jdk installed then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find `javac` in the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`. Install using

```
dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Source information: koji: http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=7988964

Comment: thanks,  why it's so confusing ?  JDK means Java Development Kit, so why there is no compiler (and other JDK stuff) in OpenJDK component ?

Comment: It can be confusing — [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) is the name of the project; it produces both a JRE and a JDK... So you end up with the OpenJDK JRE and the OpenJDK JDK!

Comment: @razor yes, exactly as Stephen explained. It is the name of the Java implementation. In fedora, parts need to use the application are in the standard packages and the parts needed to build applications are in the `-devel` subpackage, because most of the people do not use them (and it save space, bandwidth and so on)